# Multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I am studying multivariable limits from the text *Vector Calculus* by S.J. Colley.
I practiced computing limiting values of the functions of two-variables $f(x,y)$.

Here's a problem involving a function of three variables.

> Compute the limit $$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

I thought to myself, this could be for example, the scalar potential of a field in space. So, it's fun to see if the function has a limit as we get closer and closer to the origin. I would like to ask, if my proof is mathematically correct.

**Solution.**
From solid analytical geometry, a straight line in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is:

$\frac{x-x_0}{l}=\frac{y-y_0}{m}=\frac{z-z_0}{n}=r$

The straight line passing through the origin and having direction numbers $l,m,n$ is:

$\frac{x}{l}=\frac{y}{m}=\frac{z}{n}=r$

So, along this straight line with direction numbers $l,m,n$, our function takes on values

$f(x,y,z)=f(r)=\frac{2r^2l^2+3r^2m^2+r^2n^2}{r^2l^2+r^2m^2+r^2n^2}=\frac{2l^2+3m^2+n^2}{l^2+m^2+n^2}$

Along the line $x=y,z=0$, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{5}{2}$

Along the line $y=z,x=0$, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{4}{2}=2$

Along the line $x=z,y=0$, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{3}{2}$

Along the line $x=y=z$, $f(x,y,z)=\frac{6}{3}=2$

Hence, 
$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)\\\text{ along }x=y,z=0}\frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{5}{2}$

$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)\\\text{ along }y=z,x=0}\frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=2$

$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)\\\text{ along }x=z,y=0}\frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac{3}{2}$

$\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)\\\text{ along }x=y=z}\frac{2x^2+3y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}=3$

Thus, the limit of this function does not exist as $(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)$.

Comment: $x=y$ and $y=z$ are planes, not lines. I don't see how you got the limits $5/2$ and $2$. For $x=y$ you get$$\lim_{(x,z)\to(0,0)}\frac{5x^2+z^2}{x^2+z^2}$$Both $x,z$ tend to $0$.

Comment: I would like to point out that in 3D x=y is not a line, nor is any relationship you have written with fewer than two equal signs. So many of these statements are nonsensical. But provided that you find valid paths and reformulate your proof with those values, you will be all set. Right now you have only found a limit along a single line, x=y=z. Find the limit along another line.

Comment: I should correct it as $x=y,z=0$, $x=0,y=z$ and $y=0,x=z$, perhaps?

Comment: Why not take arbitrary values of $l,m,n$? You've already established that for $(l,m,n)\ne(0,0,0)$, you have a straight line of approach given by $\frac xl=\frac ym=\frac zn$. Now build on it?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, for $x=y$, the denominator is $2x^2+z^2$

Comment: Yes, pardon my error.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, yes I sense intuitively, it is path dependent. Want to ensure the proof is mathematically sound. I get it that I can take arbitrary values of $(l,m,n)$. But, there shouldn't be problem, if I go along a line entirely in the $xy$, $yz$ or $xz$ planes as well, right, I mean, I could also use $l,m,n$ as $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$ for the proof. What do you think? :)

Comment: Yes you can use those paths too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your limit was $\lim_{r\to0}\frac{2r^2l^2+3r^2m^2+r^2n^2}{r^2l^2+r^2m^2+r^2n^2}=\frac{2l^2+3m^2+n^2}{l^2+m^2+n^2}$ which depends on $(l,m,n)$ i.e. the direction of approach and hence the limit is path dependent.

You can see this by setting arbitrary values for $(l,m,n)\ne(0,0,0)$. For example, for $l=m=n=1$, your line of approach is $x=y=z$ and the limit is $6/3=2$. Along another line, say $\frac x2=\frac y2=z$, you get $21/9$. Hence the limit doesn't exist.